# Trying to scrape a page with one cookie

Tags: cookies, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape the table from the [URL](https://www.soccerstats.com/team.asp?league=england_2018&stats=20-bournemouth). I have been using requests library for a while now, along with beautiful soup, but what I don't want to venture into is using a web driver, as I have been down that road before.

So I make a request with requests, and read the response. But I get the following in the header, and nothing else. Can someone explain to me what I need to do (spent all morning on it and beginning to lose the plot)?

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SoccerSTATS.com - cookie consent</title> 
<style>
.button {

    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {padding: 10px 24px;}
.button2 {padding: 12px 28px;}
.button3 {padding: 14px 40px;}
.button4 {padding: 32px 16px;}
.button5 {padding: 16px;}
</style>  

<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookielocal(cname, cvalue, exdays) {

    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    var originpage = "/team.asp?league=england_2018&stats=20-bournemouth";
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    window.location = "//www.soccerstats.com" + originpage;
}
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The User-Agent request header contains a characteristic string that allows the network protocol peers to identify the application type, operating system, software vendor or software version of the requesting software user agent. Validating User-Agent header on server side is a common operation so be sure to use valid browser’s User-Agent string to avoid getting blocked.

*(Source: http://go-colly.org/articles/scraping_related_http_headers/)*

The only thing you need to do is to set a legitimate user-agent. Therefore add headers to **emulate a browser**. :

```
# This is a standard user-agent of Chrome browser running on Windows 10
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'
    }
```

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 

headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}
resp = requests.get('http://example.com', headers=headers).text 
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'html.parser')
```

Additionally, you can add another set of headers to pretend like a legitimate browser. Add some more headers like this:

```
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip',
'DNT' : '1', # Do Not Track Request Header
'Connection' : 'close'
}
```